# Rails - link_to path based on object's name + refactoring multiple custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm looking to simplify the `link_to` path based on thr object's name and also am looking into refactoring multiple custom actions.

I've managed to get this working below.

```
<% ServiceMenu.all.each do |menu| %>
      <tr class=" <%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
        <td><%= link_to menu.name, ("tech/""#{menu.name.parameterize}") %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

I feel this is "un-rails" like and think there's a better way to execute this.
Based on the iteration, for example `menu.name`, it will go to the URL for example `tech/oil-change`.

My controller is filled with a dozen of actions that I'm looking to *DRY* up somehow.

```
def oil_change
    @techs = Tech.joins(:services).where(services: { name: 'oil change'})
end

def muffler
    @techs = Tech.joins(:services).where(services: { name: 'muffler'})
end

etc...
etc...
etc...
etc...
```

**routes**

My routes look like the following:

```
resources :techs, :only => [:index, :show], shallow: true do
    resources :cars, only: [:new, :create]
    collection do
      get 'oil-change'
      get 'brakes'
      get 'muffler'
      etc....
      etc....
      etc....
      etc....
      etc....
    end
  end
```

**rake routes**

```
oil-change_techs / techs#oil-change
blowout_techs / techs#brakes
muffler_techs / techs#muffler
etc...._techs / techs#etc....
etc...._techs / techs#etc....
etc...._techs / techs#etc....
```

---

Is there a way for the iteration local variable `menu` (`menu.name`) to be included with the path instead of the hacked up way I have it now? Also based on the that iteration allow the `link_to` to execute a single controller action rather than having multiple controller actions?

Please know the what you see above works but am looking for simplified and *DRY* solutions if possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your routes :

```
resources :techs, :only => [:index, :show], shallow: true do
  resources :cars, only: [:new, :create]
  collection do
    get 'part/:part_name' => "techs#part", as: :part
  end
end
```

Then add the action :

```
def part
  @techs = Tech.joins(:services).where(services: { name: params[:part_name]})
end
```

and the view will be :

```
<% ServiceMenu.all.each do |menu| %>
  <tr class=" <%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
    <td><%= link_to menu.name, part_techs_path(part_name: menu.name.parameterize) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your controller was missing a parentheses. I restarted the server and am getting the following error: `undefined method 'techs_part_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd110557df8>:0x007fd110554338>`  Please advise.

Comment: @captainawesome can you run `rake routes` and tell me the what *path* is created ? I wrote the path doing a guess. Please confirm it from the `rake routes`

Comment: I meant to say your `view` was missing a parentheses.

Comment: rake routes: `GET    /techs/part/:part_name(.:format)        techs#part
`

Comment: where is the *path*  helper.. ?

Comment: rake routes: `GET    /techs/part/:part_name(.:format)        techs#part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81226/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-captain-awesome).